# Execute Python script from Php

Tags: php, python, apache2, raspberry-pi, execute

I have a PHP webpage on my raspberry pi with 2 buttons (on and off)
The on button button redirects to On.php
The off button redirects to Off.php
In "/usr/lib/cgi-bin" I have a python script that I would like to execute (script.py)
I can perfectly execute it from the terminal by typing

```
cd /usr/lib/cgi-bin
sudo python script.py
```

It works if I do it from the terminal.

The problem is the PHP file (On.php) in my "/var/www" folder.
This is what I wrote:

```
<?php
exec('cd /usr/lib/cgi-bin');
exec('sudo python script.py');
?>
```

Why is the script executing from the terminal, but not from my PHP?

Comment: Does your super user have a password?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't use sudo from a PHP script. Apache is running from an user (www-data generaly), so edit this file : `/etc/sudoers`

Then add this line :

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Care ! this will authorize all functions to be called by a PHP script, you can adapt changing "ALL" by your script or Python command.

Then precise your user in your exec command :

```
<?php
exec('sudo -u www-data python /usr/lib/cgi-bin/script.py')
```

Comment: Does this remove passwords? Because i have the server port forwarded publicly. I wouldn't want anyone just entering my server.

Comment: It will remove password the user www-data, that's why you can ask NOPASSWD to some command, like `NOPASSWD:python`. It won't change something for other users.

Comment: Ok, i'm not an expert, i just wanted to make sure nobody could hack in my raspberry as the superuser or any other user.

Comment: This allows to use sudo without password, only the user `www-data`. This user can't connect through SSH so no risk.

Comment: sudo `www-data` without password is not safe at all. it's not about SSH, it's about Nginx, Apache2 or etc.. If one of the servers were exploited, it can execute remote commands. If it has `root` privilege, some happy some sad. It happens always.

Answer (score 4):

Try this out, it should be working:

```
<?php 
system("cd /usr/lib/cgi-bin");
system("sudo python script.py");
?>
```

Or even this:

```
<?php 
system("cd /usr/lib/cgi-bin && sudo python script.py");
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

On an older Raspbian distribution you need to place your file in `/var/www/file.py`. So in your file.php you add:

```
{
    exec("sudo python /var/www/file.py");
}
```

On a newer Raspbian Jessie you need to place your file in `/var/www/html/file.py`, so in your file.php you need to add:

```
{
    exec("sudo python /var/www/html/file.py");
}
```

Or just any file.py

```
<?php
{
  exec("sudo python test.py");
}
```

?>

Note: For this to work you need to edit a file first to add these lines to allow passwordless sudo

`sudo nano /etc/sudoers`

then go to the bottom and add this

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL<br>
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Don't ever add www-data to sudoers with `NOPASSWD: ALL`! This can turn into a very big security problem. See @dotslash's comment above

Comment: yes is can if it is online this pi is just a house remote that is all. For the people that read the don't do this to control over the internet

Comment: So? If it's connected to a network, it can be compromised if someone tries hard enough. Just don't do it. There are better ways, such as Alberto Pagani's answer.