# Executing python script from a PHP site -- do I need Django? Can it be done on a raspberry pi?

Tags: php, python, mysql, django, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on a program that utilizes Python scripts that pull information from a MySQL database. The MySQL database is managed from a PHP site interface (so HTML forms and buttons and the such). I have this all set up on a raspberry pi and it works. But I want to add some more functionality.

Specifically I want to be able to **execute certain python scripts from    the PHP site**. I want it to be as simple as a press of a button,    literally.

Is this a scenario where I should use Django? I've never used it before but have read about how it connects Python with the web. I found an answer to a similar question but I'm wondering If I need to set up anything special on my apache server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811462/5609876

I even made a little picture for a visual representation of my program incase my explanation wasn't good enough:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need django at all.

If all you want to do is execute a Python script from PHP - assuming you have already written the script and stored it somewhere:

First, assign execute permissions on the Python script to the user that is running the PHP code. Normally, this is the same user that is running Apache. Usually this is called `www-data` or `apache` or something similar. The user will be listed in the Apache configuration file.

Then, on your PHP side, all you really need is [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
<?php

    exec('/path/to/python /path/to/your/script.py')

?>
```

Comment: How do I give a user execute permissions on a Python Script?

Comment: [`chmod u+x /the/path/to/script.py`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If the [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function is allowed on your server, you can use that to run your Python script through Bash. `shell_exec` returns the output of the bash call. The only thing you have to make sure of is that `shell_exec` isn't disabled in your server's php.ini file (look for the line `disable_functions shell_exec`).

If your python script is called `mypythonscript.py` and is in the same directory as the PHP file, you can run it like this:

```
<? shell_exec('python mypythonscript.py'); ?>
```

Comment: Can I send commands to the bash from PHP?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I just added an example of usage of this command.