# How to upload and access a Python script in cPanel?

Tags: php, python, execute

I have a Python file, which is an automation script from GitHub. I want that script to be executed by a PHP page.

For example, I have an `index.php` page, and it has a button saying `Start script`. Upon clicking the button, a Python script, `instabot.py`, should be executed. Is this possible in cPanel? My web host is Hostgator.

Comment: you can use ftp to copy your .py file to your host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using information from [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811253/execute-python-script-from-php), you might wanna use `exec()` to run a Python script from PHP. Like:

```
exec('python /path/to/file/instabot.py');
```

According to Hostgator's [documentation](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/perl-and-python-scripts), Python scripts should have permissions set at `755`.

Uploading your Python scripts will be the same as uploading any file to a web host, through the use of FTP or cPanel itself.

Comment: What if I need to print the output of file in php page. ?

Comment: @HannanMustajab You're welcome. You might wanna click the check mark next to this question.

As for printing the output, instead of `exec()`, use `shell_exec()`. So to print the output, do, `$output = shell_exec(...); echo $output;`.